# Matrix reduction over the field modulo 5

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to transform a given matrix over modulo 5, but apparently I need to reduce the question further, but I have no clue how! I'm fairly certain that the form I have now is correct but I could always be wrong.

\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3&2\\1&2&0&0\\4&2&1&4\end{bmatrix}

Using elementary operations I get:

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&3\\0&2&3&2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Have I made a mistake? or is there some other operation I can perform to simplify further. My suspicions lie on multiplying by the inverse of one of the variables, but I can't seem to come up with anything useful. Thank your for your time and for reading the question! All answers appreciated.

Comment: Is this the original matrix? What do you want to do with the matrix?

Comment: That is echelon form, but not reduced echelon form. To achieve that, multiply the second row by the inverse of $2$ in the field of five elements.